# F# remove duplicates from a string [] list

Tags: arrays, list, f#, duplicates

I have a program that results in an [] list, and I'm trying to remove near duplicated arrays from the list. An example of the list is...

```
[
   [|
      "Jackson";
      "Stentzke";
      "22";
      "001"
    |];
    [|
      "Jackson";
      "Stentzke";
      "22";
      "002"
    |];
    [|
      "Alec";
      "Stentzke";
      "18";
      "003"
    |]
]
```

Basically I'm trying to write a function that would read over the list and remove all examples of near identical data. So the final returned [] list should look like...

```
[
    [|
      "Alec";
      "Stentzke";
      "18";
      "003"
    |]
]
```

I've tried a number of functions to try and get this result or something close to it that can work with. My current attempt is this...

```
let removeDuplicates (arrayList: string[]list) =
    let list = arrayList|> List.map(fun aL -> 
        let a = arrayList|> List.map(fun aL2 -> 
                try
                    match (aL.GetValue(0).Equals(aL2.GetValue(0))) && (aL.GetValue(2).Equals(aL2.GetValue(2))) && (aL.GetValue(3).Equals(aL2.GetValue(3))) with
                    | false -> aL2
                    | _ -> [|""|]
                with
                | ex -> [|""|]
            )
        a 
                                              )
    list |> List.concat |> List.distinct
```

But all this returns is the a reversed version on the input []list.

Does anyone know how to remove near duplicated arrays from a list?

Comment: your definition on near identical if both the first name and the last name is the same?

Comment: What does "near identical" exactly mean? In your example you are equalling the first and fourth arguments and none of the data meets that criteria.

Comment: Try using `List.distinctBy`. It's missing from the [List module documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.list-module-%5bfsharp%5d) at the moment, but the [`Seq.distinctBy` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.distinctby%5B't,'key%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) should give you the general idea: you write a "projection" function that, given a list item, returns only the subset of data that you want to consider for the purposes of deciding if this item is "unique enough" for your purposes.

Comment: BTW, when you call `List.map` followed immediately by `List.concat`, that's usually a sign that you should be using [`List.collect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.collect%5b%27t%2c%27u%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d) instead.

Comment: near identical, meaning the first, second and third values are the same, but the fourth value isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a dictionary/map based on the fields you consider identical then just remove any duplicate occurance. Here's a simply and mechanical way, assuming `xs` is the List you specified above:

```
type DataRec = { key:string
                 fname:string
                 lname:string
                 id1:string
                 id2:string}

let dataRecs = xs |> List.map (fun x -> {key=x.[0]+x.[1]+x.[2];fname=x.[0];lname=x.[1];id1=x.[2];id2=x.[3]})

dataRecs |> Seq.groupBy (fun x -> x.key) 
         |> Seq.filter (fun x -> Seq.length (snd x) = 1)
         |> Seq.collect snd
         |> Seq.map (fun x -> [|x.fname;x.lname;x.id1;x.id2|])
         |> Seq.toList
```

Output:

> val it : string [] list = [[|"Alec"; "Stentzke"; "18"; "003"|]]

It basically creates a key from the first three items, groups by it, filters out anything over 2 counst, and then maps back to an array.

Comment: So;

    type user = { fname : string; lname : string; id1 : int; id2 : int} ?
And I'd replace key with user?

Comment: you can also create a `type user = {key:string,row:string []}` where the row item just holds the whole array. You can then factor out the `Seq.map` line where i turn it back to an array.

Comment: Just configured it for my program and it works. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your code and comments don't match up very well. Considering your comments "the first, second and third values are the same", I believe this can get you in the right track:

```
let removeDuplicates (arrayList: string[]list) =
    arrayList |> Seq.distinctBy (fun elem ->  (elem.[0] , elem.[1] , elem.[2]))
```

The result of this against your input data is a two element list containing:

```
[
 [|
  "Jackson";
  "Stentzke";
  "22";
  "001"
 |];
 [|
  "Alec";
  "Stentzke";
  "18";
  "003"
 |]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using some Linq:

```
let comparer (atMost) = 
    { new System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string[]> with
            member __.Equals(a, b) = 
                Seq.zip a b
                    |> Seq.sumBy (fun (a',b') -> System.StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Compare(a', b') |> abs |> min 1)
                    |> ((>=) atMost)
            member __.GetHashCode(a) = 1
    }

System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupBy(data, id, comparer 1)
    |> Seq.choose (fun g -> match Seq.length g with | 1 -> Some g.Key | _ -> None)
```

The comparer allows for `atMost : int` number of differences between two arrays.